# Retrieval of certificate/keys related information from keystore in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore, android-security, android-securityexception

I am new to Android. I have created the Keystore file. Under the PrivateActivity class, I have also loaded the Keystore. My task is to get any key/certificate-related information after putting the name of the alias (that I have created),  on the android emulator . I have also changed the path in Gradle build, but I wanted to understand if I have to add the Keystore file name or path somewhere in the code or I have to write a method that will retrieve all the keys and certificate-related information from the Keystore? Because after writing the method, I couldn't get the certificate/key-related information.
PrivateActivity.java

````
``` package org.jssec.android.activity.privateactivity;```

```import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.InputStream;```


import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

//Appropriate libraries need to be also imported

public class PrivateActivity extends Activity {

    private KeyStore my_ks;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.private_activity);

        // Handle the received Intent carefully and securely,
        // even though the Intent was sent from the same application.

        Intent intent=this.getIntent();
        PrivateUserActivity.keystore_info param = (PrivateUserActivity.keystore_info) intent.getSerializableExtra("CL_k");


        //CODE MUST BE ADDED HERE IN ORDER TO HANDLE the COLLECTED OBJECT from the Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Cl_k");


    }

    public void onReturnResultClick(View view) throws KeyStoreException,
            UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchProviderException {

        // Sensitive information can be sent since it is sending
        // and receiving all within the same application.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PrivateUserActivity.class);


        //Create instance
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null);
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();





        //CODE MUST BE ADDED HERE IN ORDER TO send the appropriate values to the PrivateUserActivity
        //i.e. the "Sensitive Info" value should be changed with something different



       //// return new KeyPair (publicKey,privateKey);

        intent.putExtra("RESULT", "Sensitive Info");

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}```

Another class is this PrivateUserActivity.java
```/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012-2019 Japan Smartphone Security Association
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.jssec.android.activity.privateactivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.InputStream;


import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

//Appropriate libraries need to be also imported

public class PrivateActivity extends Activity {

    private KeyStore my_ks;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.private_activity);

        // Handle the received Intent carefully and securely,
        // even though the Intent was sent from the same application.

        Intent intent=this.getIntent();
        PrivateUserActivity.keystore_info param = (PrivateUserActivity.keystore_info) intent.getSerializableExtra("CL_k");


        //CODE MUST BE ADDED HERE IN ORDER TO HANDLE the COLLECTED OBJECT from the Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Cl_k");


    }

    public void onReturnResultClick(View view) throws KeyStoreException,
            UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchProviderException {

        // Sensitive information can be sent since it is sending
        // and receiving all within the same application.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PrivateUserActivity.class);


        //Create instance
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        ks.load(null);
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();





        //CODE MUST BE ADDED HERE IN ORDER TO send the appropriate values to the PrivateUserActivity
        //i.e. the "Sensitive Info" value should be changed with something different



       //// return new KeyPair (publicKey,privateKey);

        intent.putExtra("RESULT", "Sensitive Info");

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Not clear exactly what your problem is, but if you are using KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore"), there is no file you need to load.
Android manages the keys and any underlying files automatically.

To actually generate a file saved in the Android keystore, you need to specify "AndroidKeyStore" when you setup the generation parameters. 
See the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore